# C++ const char* overloading confusion

Tags: c++, templates, char, constants, overloading

I don't understand why this program produces the output below.

```
void blah(const char* )       {printf("const char*\n");}
void blah(const std::string&) {printf("const string ref\n");}
template<class t>
void blah(t)                  {printf ("unknown\n");}

int main(int, char*)
{        
  blah("hi");
  char a[4];
  blah(a);
  std::string s;
  blah(s);
  getch();
}
```

Outputs:

```
const char*
unknown
const string
```

In VS2008. It is willing to convert the std::string to a const reference, but why won't it convert the char* to a const char* and use the overload?

Comment: it's simply choosing the closest match from the options you've given it. `class t` can match `char*` exactly, with no conversion needed, so it chooses that one in preference.

Comment: (incidentally, the `string` example isn't being converted to a reference, but rather it defaults to being passed by reference and only becomes a pass-by-copy if that has no matches. Templates can't change the reference-ness (except for a special case for rvalue references), so that template can only accept classes by copy)

Comment: What do you mean that the string "defaults to being passed by reference"? Why can't the type `t` be `std::string&`? What gets me is that neither calls are exact matches. Neither the `string` nor the `char*` is `const`.

Comment: As I said, "it defaults to being passed by reference and only becomes a pass-by-copy if that has no matches". In other words, it tries `string&` then `const string&` *then* `string` and `const string`. The template can *only* be the latter 2 (because "Templates can't change the reference-ness"). The first doesn't exist, so the first good match is the second.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `"hi"` is `const char[3]`, whereas the type of `a` is `char[4]`.

So, the first call requires only array-to-pointer conversion (aka "decay"). The third call requires only binding an object to a reference-to-const (I don't think "converting" is the correct terminology for reference-binding, although I may be mistaken). The second call would require array decay *and* a pointer conversion in order to call the `const char*` overload.

I claim without actually checking the overload resolution text in the standard that this extra step is what makes the template a better match than the `const char*` overload.

Btw, if you change `"unknown\n"` to `"%s\n", typeid(t).name()` then you can see what the type `t` was deduced as. For your code, it is deduced as `char*` (because arrays can't be passed by value), but see what happens if you change the template to take a `t&` parameter instead of `t`. Then `t` can be deduced as `char[4]`.

Comment: This seems incorrect. `blah((char*)"hi")` still produces `unknown`.

Comment: @TysonJacobs of course it does. Just as `blah((const char*)a)` will produce `const char*`. An *explicit* cast happens before function resolution, so the function call would have to convert it *back*!

Comment: @Dave but your point was that the template matched the call to `blah("hi")` because it had to "decay" the array to a pointer _and_ convert the pointer type. Casting to `char*` eliminates one of those steps.

Comment: @TysonJacobs one of us is confused. `blah("hi")` goes to `const char*`, whereas the cast changes that to `unknown`. That is exactly the behaviour I would expect from the rules me and Steve Jessop mentioned, so I don't see the problem…

Comment: @Dave sorry that was confusing, I should have said `blah((char*)a)`, but of course the output is the same in either case. It has nothing to do with the "decay" from array to pointer. So what is the reason for the asymmetry in behavior?

Comment: @TysonJacobs: `blah((char*)a)` requires a pointer conversion to call the `const char*` overload. So the fact that it selects the template seems entirely consistent with my claim/guess that it's the pointer conversion that makes the `const char*` overload a worse match than the template. The interesting thing about the array decay, is that although it's a conversion it *doesn't* result in a worse match. In short the reason for the asymmetry is that if you start with a non-const array or ptr then you need a pointer conversion to call the `const char*` overload. With a const array you don't.